# Sort ajax data in table with tablesorter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to use tablesorter.js but im running into issues when using ajax to update my table. I followed [the code on this page](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html) but it doesn't seem to be working properly. One thing i also notice is that the code doesnt work properly even on the example website. When i click "append new table data" it adds the data to the table but it isn't sorting it correctly. If i copy the javascript code and paste it into the console, it works fine and sorts the table correctly. The code im using is the following:

```
var updateTableSort = function(){
    var table = $('#transaction-table')
    //tells table sorter that table has been updated
    table.trigger("update");
    //re sorts after table has been updated based on 
   //current sort patern
    var sorting=table.get(0).config.sortList;
    table.trigger('sorton', [sorting]);
}
```

Again, if i copy and past this into console it works fine, but when i have it in my success ajax function, it doesnt sort the table properly. Any help figuring out what the issue is would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). It automatically resorts the table after an update:

```
// pass anything BUT false and the table will resort
// using the current sort
$("table").trigger("update", [false]);
```

Here is the [updated append data to the table using ajax demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-ajax.html):

```
$(function() {

  $("table").tablesorter({ theme : 'blue' });

  $("#ajax-append").click(function() {

    $.get("assets/ajax-content.html", function(html) {

      // append the "ajax'd" data to the table body
      $("table tbody").append(html);

      // let the plugin know that we made a update
      // the resort flag set to anything BUT false (no quotes) will
      // trigger an automatic
      // table resort using the current sort
      var resort = true;
      $("table").trigger("update", [resort]);

      // triggering the "update" function will resort the table using the
      // current sort; since version 2.0.14
      // use the following code to change the sort; set sorting column and
      // direction, this will sort on the first and third column
      // var sorting = [[2,1],[0,0]];
      // $("table").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Awesome this fix worked!! not sure what the issue was with the method i was using, but thanks for the new solution!